# Check if blender's console is turned on using python?

Tags: python, blender

I only see a bpy.ops.wm.console_toggle(), which does indeed allow me to toggle the console on and off, but I want to make sure that the console is indeed ON.  The variable foo = bpy.ops.wm.console_toggle() does not seem to contain any state data on the console.

Is there a way to check whether the console is visible or not?  I want to ensure it is open when the rest of my script is running.

Comment: [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3155/how-to-know-if-the-system-console-is-open) from the Blender stack exchange suggests it might not be possible (though it is a few years old)